# Script to open sequential links each time you click the button

Tags: javascript, html, web

I got a script that opens links randomly ... but I needed to know how I create a script to open a link by myself and then return to the initial one. Eg... Click on the button and it opens link1. Click it again and it opens link2 ... again and opens link3 .... then opens link4 .... and then opens link1 again.
I'm using this script to make him open the link randomly .... but I need it to be sequential and after opening the last link he opens link1 again. Can you help me guys?! 
Best regards!
Alex.

---

```
<script>
<! -
/ *
Random Links Button
* /

// Specify the links to work at random below. You can enter as many as needed
var randomlinks=new Array()

randomlinks[0]="https://website1.com"
randomlinks[1]="https://website2.com"
randomlinks[2]="https://website3.com"
randomlinks[3]="https://website4.com"

function randomlink(){
window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
}
// - END OF SCRIPT-

</script>
```

---

Comment: If you are using php or any server side language, u can send the index  of the array through the link and then use it as a get variable.

Comment: I do not know if this is working very well .... I need a solution for each visit of the site enter a link from a list of a sequence. In this case he always takes the first one if he gives an F5 (when hit a new session)... It had to be an exact sequence, but in different sessions ... first visitor1 clicks this button and goes to link1 ... visitande2 goes to link2 and so on ... In this case I think I would have to create some variable to register in the wordpress database so that it can check which the last link in the list was shown .... Did I get to be clear? I'm sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify a global variable, which acts as a click counter, from within the function. eg:

```
var randomlinks=new Array();
    randomlinks[0]="https://website1.com"
    randomlinks[1]="https://website2.com"
    randomlinks[2]="https://website3.com"
    randomlinks[3]="https://website4.com"

var i=0;

function clickroundrobin(e){
    if( i >= randomlinks.length )i=0;
    var url=randomlinks[i];
    i++;
    window.location=url;
}
```

To test:

```js
   var randomlinks=new Array();
    randomlinks[0]="https://website1.com"
    randomlinks[1]="https://website2.com"
    randomlinks[2]="https://website3.com"
    randomlinks[3]="https://website4.com"
    
   var i=0;

   function clickroundrobin(e){
    if( i >= randomlinks.length )i=0;
    var url=randomlinks[i];
    i++;
    //window.location=url;
    alert( url )
   }
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='clickroundrobin(event)'>Click</a>
```

Comment: I do not know if this is working very well .... I need a solution for each visit of the site enter a link from a list of a sequence. In this case he always takes the first one if he gives an F5 (when hit a new session)... It had to be an exact sequence, but in different sessions ... first visitor1 clicks this button and goes to link1 ... visitande2 goes to link2 and so on ... In this case I think I would have to create some variable to register in the wordpress database so that it can check which the last link in the list was shown .... Did I get to be clear? I'm sorry for not being clear.

Comment: `"for each visit of the site"` suggests that you are looking for a `round-robin` solution that affects all users rather than a single user OR you mean that the state needs to be maintained `"per-user"` Please try to clarify you EXACT requirements because these distinctions were not made clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window.open and by iterating the variable value on the button and pass the it as array index

```
<button onclick="randomlink()" >Random Link</button>
<script>
Links = []
Links.push("https://alloytech.wordpress.com");
Links.push("https://www.google.com/");
Links.push("https://www.youtube.com/");
Links.push("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
var randomParam=0;
function randomlink() {
randomParam = randomParam >= Links.length?0:randomParam;
window.open(Links[randomParam],'popUpWindow','height=400,width=800,scrollbars=yes');  
randomParam++;
}
</script>
```

I think this is what you are expecting

Comment: You could explain what you did differently, and why. Also, in the description they do not want it 'random', but rather 'sequential'.

Comment: I do not know if this is working very well .... I need a solution for each visit of the site enter a link from a list of a sequence. In this case he always takes the first one if he gives an F5 (when hit a new session)... It had to be an exact sequence, but in different sessions ... first visitor1 clicks this button and goes to link1 ... visitande2 goes to link2 and so on ... In this case I think I would have to create some variable to register in the wordpress database so that it can check which the last link in the list was shown .... Did I get to be clear? I'm sorry for not being clear.

Comment: then you should have a iterative value in the database and you should increment it whenever the page loads , also if it reaches the max limit , you should reset the iterator and pass that one in the button click function , so that you will be getting different window for different users